# Pandas: conditional shift in blocks with reset

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to shift data in a Pandas dataframe in the following manner from this:

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 10 |

To this:

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

In short, I want to move the data 3 rows down each time a new cycle for a time block begins.

Have not been able to find solution on this, as it seems my English is quite limited not knowing how to describe the problem without an example.

Edit:

Both solutions work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can `shift` per group:

```
df['value_shift'] = df.groupby(df['time'].eq(1).cumsum())['value'].shift(2)
```

output:

```
   time  value  value_shift
0     1      1          NaN
1     2      2          NaN
2     3      3          1.0
3     4      4          2.0
4     5      5          3.0
5     1      6          NaN
6     2      7          NaN
7     3      8          6.0
8     4      9          7.0
9     5     10          8.0
```

Comment: @not_speshal yes +1! The condition for restarting is slightly different ;) I'd suggest you use `le(0)` to enable restarting on identical values

Comment: @idiot_at_work note the the conditions not_speshal and I used are slightly different (restarting on 1 vs restarting on switch from one time to a lesser time), in the provided example this doesn't make a difference ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `groupby`:

```
df["value"] = df.groupby(df["time"].diff().lt(0).cumsum())["value"].shift(2)

>>> df
   time  value
0     1    NaN
1     2    NaN
2     3    1.0
3     4    2.0
4     5    3.0
5     1    NaN
6     2    NaN
7     3    6.0
8     4    7.0
9     5    8.0
```